# What is this space with infinitely many different points with distance $1$ between any two different points?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

I'm reading Mac Lane's: *Mathematics, Form and Function*:

> [...] There are also bizarre examples - such as "a space" with infinitely many different points, with distance $1$ between any two different points.

What is this *bizarre* space?

Comment: There is not going to be any way to place this as a subset of anything familiar. You just need to take it on its own merits.

Comment: @WillJagy I don't get it.

Comment: You can easily place a finite number of points in Euclidean space at mutual distance $1,$ but not infinitely many. As an alternative, we can take suitable multiples of $\cos n \theta$ and $\sin n \theta,$ where distance is given by the $L^2$ inner product on, say, continuous periodic functions on $[0,2 \pi].$ I guess that is the most concrete manifestation available.

Comment: Up to isometry, the quote you have is *already* a nearly complete definition of a space. The only thing it's missing is specifying which specific cardinality the space has.

Answer (score 1):

This space can be defined using any set actually. It is generated by the metric called the discrete metric.

Define $d: M \times M \rightarrow M$ by

$$ d(x, y) = 0 \iff x = y \;\;\text{and }$$
$$d(x, y) = 1 \iff x \neq y$$

This is what is called the discrete metric and is defined for any set $M$. You can show for yourself that $d$ actually constitutes a metric.

And the space $(M, d)$ is as you wish. The distance between any two different points is $1$. As long as you pick $M$ to be infinite, all your requirements are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Take all the continuous functions that satisfy $f(x +2\pi) = f(x)$ for all real $x.$ Make a distance on these by 
$$  d(f,g) = \sqrt{ \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} (f(x) - g(x))^2 dx }  $$ With this distance function, we can make an infinite set of functions that are distance $1$ apart with
$$ f_n(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \sin (nx).     $$
The word "point" refers here to a function.